# How to compute molecular formula?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, stoichiometry

I have the following question to solve:

> Tungsten, $\ce{W}$, and chlorine, $\ce{Cl}$, form a series of compounds with the following compositions:
>   \begin{array}{rr}
> \text{Mass % W}  & \text{Mass % Cl}\\
> \hline
>     72.17     &  27.83\\
>     56.45     &  43.55\\
>     50.91     &  49.09\\
>     46.36     &  53.64\\
> \end{array}
>   If a molecule of each compound contains only one tungsten atom, what are the formulas for the four compounds?

My answer is as follows:

For one gram of tungsten, chlorine has mass
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{27.83}{72.17} &= 0.3302~\mathrm{g}\\[3pt]
\frac{43.55}{56.45} &= 0.7715~\mathrm{g}\\[3pt]
\frac{49.09}{50.91} &= 0.9643~\mathrm{g}\\[3pt]
\frac{53.64}{46.36} &= 1.157~\mathrm{g}.\\
\end{align}
$$

Since $\frac{0.7715}{0.3302}\approx\frac{7}{3}$, $\frac{0.9643}{0.3302}\approx3$, and $\frac{1.157}{0.3302}\approx\frac{7}{2}$, the number of atoms of chlorine for a given mass of tungsten are respectively in the ratio $6:14:18:21$.

So if a molecule of each compound contains only one tungsten atom, the formulas are $\ce{WCl_{6}}$, $\ce{WCl_{14}}$, $\ce{WCl_{18}}$, and $\ce{WCl_{21}}$.

Is this correct?

Comment: No. Look up "empirical formula" in a chemistry book or Google it.

Comment: This question served as a *bad example* for the [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/141). (It might be quite a good fit nowadays though.)

Answer (score 8):

> We don't have a homework policy yet, but I'm quite sure that it will be against providing full answers.

Hints:

- You're supposed to take into account molar masses. The ratios in a formula are *molar* ratios, so you need to use those, not mass ratios.
- Read up a bit on emperical formulae, as Janice suggested.

Comment: This answer is preventing the question from being deleted no?

Comment: Just my opinion, the question should be kept since the homework policy uses it as an example of a bad question. That's especially true since the other two bad examples there have already been deleted.

Comment: It seems that we may have become more lax on homework questions because if OP posted this question today, I think this would be considered pretty good.